# Is it possible to run script in foreground via Ansible

Tags: ansible, zenity

I use Ansible to push something to nodes and I wanted to use Zenity to warn the user who is using a node that I am doing something but I am unable to figure out how to run script displaying on nodes foreground. It is possible to run a script via Ansible but to display it on the node instead of the Control Machine?

Comment: I don't understand why you say "in the background". ansible is design to perform task more on nodes (called target) than the control machine. Please read the help section [ask] and add clarification to the question (button [edit]).

Comment: @baptistemm I never said “in the background”

Comment: sorry I meant "in foreground"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out all I needed to do is to use script module to run my local script on the nodes.

```
---
- hosts: targets

  tasks:   
  - name: Notify of imminent upgrade
    script: /home/hero/loading.sh
```

The script being something like this.

```
#!/bin/bash
DISPLAY=:0 zenity --warning
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/2883/45896) to get an idea how to notify users using `notify-send`. I would suggest to write a dedicated script where you can pass the message as argument tinstead of putting that inline in ansible

so you can do

```
- hosts: targets
  tasks:

  - name: Notify of imminent upgrade
    shell: "/opt/myscripts/notify-connected-users Upgrade and reboot coming soon"

  - name: Let give some time to users to read the message
    pause:
      minutes: 1

  - name: continue the operation
    ...
```

Comment: This still shows on my terminal, I wanted to display some dialog for a user not for me.

Comment: The script I've referred to is supposed to send the notification to all the users.